# Does preconnecting to our own host affect loading speed?

Tags: javascript, html

I was reading about preconnecting scripts in order to speed up site loading. I had this question which I searched for and found nothing. Maybe because it doesn't make any sense. Anyway, here's the question:

Does this affect load speed?

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="/images/">
```

By `/images/` I mean the `images` folder in the same host that the index.html file exists in.

Alternatively, I can explain like this:
Imagine `example.com` is the same host that hosts the `index.html` file which has this piece of code in its header tag:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="example.com/images/">
```

And of course, any image in the site is in the `images` folder. Now, does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preconnect)…

> The preconnect keyword for the rel attribute of the  element is a hint to browsers that the user is likely to need resources from the target resource's origin, and therefore the browser can likely improve the user experience by preemptively initiating a connection to that origin. Preconnecting speeds up future loads from a given origin by preemptively performing part or all of the handshake (DNS+TCP for HTTP, and DNS+TCP+TLS for HTTPS origins).

It seems that should answer your question without further comment needed.

Although when the origin is the same as the page comes from, it seems unlikely it would make any difference, since a connection will already be open and likely kept alive already to grab those resources.

Hope that helps.